# how to get data when redirect to new page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

I,m using public API thesportdb
and I created function, the function is when card is clicking, and redirect to new page and show data,
but i have a problem, the problem is when i clicked the card , data can't be process in new page .

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/search_all_leagues.php?',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    data : {
        's' : 'Soccer'
    },

    success: function(result){
        let league = result.countrys;

        $.each(league, function(i, data){
            $('#club-list').append(`
                <div class="col-md-4 p-2">
                    <div class="card shadow" data-id="${data.idLeague}" onClick="console.log(`+data.idLeague+`);">
                      <img src="`+ data.strBadge +`" class="card-img-top p-2" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">`+ data.strLeague +`</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`);
        });

        $('.card').on('click', function(){

            $.ajax({

                url : 'https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/lookup_all_teams.php?',
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    'id' : this.dataset.id
                },

                success: function(result){
                    let team = result.teams;

                        $('#club-detail').load('league.php', function(){
                                $.each(team, function(i, data){
                                    $('#club-detail').append(`
                                        <div class="col-md-4 p-2">
                                            <div class="card shadow">
                                              <img src="`+ data.strTeamBadge +`" class="card-img-top p-2" alt="...">
                                              <div class="card-body">
                                                <p class="card-text">`+ data.strTeam +`</p>
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>`);
                            });
                        });

                    console.log(team);
                }

            });

        });
    } 
});
```

index.php here is the code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Football Match</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" id="club-list">



      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

league.php here is the code :
data can't show here, this is the new page when i click the card in index.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Football Match</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" id="club-detail">



      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why is there redirection at all? jQuery and ajax are usually used to avoid such problem. 

But in any case, use local storage. Problems are how to know which data is correct, that is what you must solve.

Comment: I wanna show data of card click function, I get data in console.log(team); but i dont know send data to new page

Comment: store data in local storage when received, redirect to second page and render data if there is data in local storage. otherwise, redesign approach.

Comment: Ajax is supposed to be the solution in the scenario you mentioned, not the problem. It updates the page without user noticing the reload. you can write an ajax (after redirection) on the next page page_load event to pull the data.